# Uniqueness validation failure even though :email validation is removed from User model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, tdd

I am having a trouble with getting my Rails test to pass.

I am following the *Rails Crash Course: A No-Nonsense Guide to Rails Development* by Anthony Lewis and have double-checked & compared the code from the textbook. This test aims to create a valid user, and check if the validations are working.

So, the steps I took to reproduce the error:

1. Open User.rb model, remove `uniqueness: true` line (to help diagnose problem).
2. Run `rake test test/models/user_test.rb`

Which results in the following error:

```
  Error:
        UserTest#test_saves_with_valid_attributes:
        ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: posts.id: INSERT INTO "posts" ("title", "body", "url", "type", "created_at", "updated_at", "id", "user_id") VALUES ('MyString', 'MyText', 'MyString', NULL, '2018-04-23 07:01:37.793314', '2018-04-23 07:01:37.793314', 980190962, 980190962)
```

Can someone explain why I still get an uniqueness validation error even though I removed `uniqueness:true` from `:email`?

Here's what my User.rb looks like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :subscriptions, foreign_key: :follower_id, dependent: :destroy

    has_many :leaders, through: :subscriptions 

    has_many :reverse_subscriptions, foreign_key: :leader_id, 
    class_name: 'Subscription', dependent: :destroy

    has_many :followers, through: :reverse_subscriptions

    has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :text_posts, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :image_posts, dependent: :destroy

    def following?(leader)
        leaders.include? leader
    end

    def follow!(leader)
        if leader != self && !following?(leader)
            leaders << leader
        end
    end

    has_secure_password

    **validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true** 

    def timeline_user_ids
        leader_ids + [id]
    end



end
```

What my user_test.rb contains:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # test "the truth" do
  #   assert true
  # end

  test "saves with valid attributes" do
    user = User.new(
      email: "user@example.com",
      password: "password",
      password_confirmation: "password"
    )
    assert user.save
  end
end
```

I have a feeling its something to do with the fixtures but the files are Rails 5.1 defaults.

Comment: Check `users` table for uniq index on `email` column

Answer (score 0):

Look your message error:

`ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: posts.id ...`

So I think hmm... maybe the post.id is duplicate with other one in your database. Please check again :)